# Add properties to JavaScript Error object?

Tags: javascript, error-handling, javascript-objects

I see that according to [MDN - Error](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error) documentation, the `Error` object might have different behavior across different browsers.
I'd like to check what is your opinion regarding adding properties on the default `Error` object.

In my specific code, I'd like to *tag* an `Error` object with my own tag name for further use, which means -> adding a property to the object as follows:

```js
const error = new Error('some message')
if(someConditionExist()){
    error.__myTag = 'tag1';
}
else {
    error.__myTag = 'tag2';
}
//then throwing the error and catch it elsewhere...
```

I haven't seen any guidelines what are the implications (if any...) of such thing.

Is any of you have any concerns? Have you encountered any issues across different browsers?

Comment: Sure, that's fine. The only concern might be a property name that could (in the future?) collide with a native one

Comment: @Bergi - right... of course

Comment: [Example at MDN: Error#custom_error_types](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error#custom_error_types)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Well, we could argue wether you should add custom properties to built-in objects, but something like this could work:

```
class CustomError extends Error {
  constructor(tag) {
    super();
    this.__tag = tag;
  }
};

const customError = new CustomError('tag1');

console.log(customError.__tag); // 'tag1'
```

Comment: I'm aware of that option, though, I don't have any kind of real extension here. Usually you would extend a class to take its behavior further. Here I have the capability of adding the property already, right?

Comment: I don't see much difference to what the OP is doing here, except that `class extends Error` requires native ES6 support in the environment

Comment: I like this approach! I used it and also included a constructor argument for the message value to pass in the `super` call. I proposed an edit to your answer to include it in the example.

Answer (score 6):

Event though an old question, Another solution might be, in some cases to add properties "on the fly" with Object.assign()

```
const error = new Error('some message')
const withTag = Object.assign(error , { __tag: "tag_1"})
```

Just notice that on on console.error() in some browsers you wont see the additional properties that you added.